# How to perform unit testing of Android app on a Windows command line?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, windows, unit-testing

I've written an Android app that works fine running in Eclipse with an
Android simulator.

However, a portion of the program is purely computational, and I'd
like to unit test that portion in a command window using "javac" and
"java" commands, using "System.out.print" to get output.  Is there any
simple way to do that, without copying all the source files from the
Eclipse workspace into another directory?

Alternatively, I've tried to do something similar under Eclipse:

1. I wrote a program "UnitTest.java" that calls the computational
   code, and everything compiles correctly.  UnitTest.java contains a
   "main" program.
2. I created a new "Debug Configuration" -- UnitTest as a Java
   application.
3. In the JRE tab, I pointed the Runtime JRE to the "Alternate JRE",
   which is jdk1.7.0_13 in C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_13.
4. However, when I try to run it, I get: Cannot connect to VM Socket
   operation on nonsocket: configureBlocking

I'm still able to run the Android app when I launch the original
configuration.

The ideal situation is that I would be able to run either the Android
app or the unit test as either a Java app in Eclipse or as a command
line app in Windows.

Is there any way to do this, or am I asking for the moon?

Comment: Could you not refactor the code to move the computational part into another class and then write a JUnit test for it?

Comment: The computational portion is already in a separate class.  How do I
set up the JUnit test so that it will run as a local Java app (not an
Android app)?

Comment: Tried it, and got the same "Cannot connect to VM" message.